# HTML checkbox turns on text magnify function in JavaScript/Jquery but can't turn it off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm writing some code to magnify text once you hover over it if you have the Magnify checkbox selected. It works to turn on the magnifier but I can't figure out how to turn it off once the checkbox is unselected.

**textmagn.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Text Magnification</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lines.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script src="javasc.js"></script>
            <a>This is a sentece.</a>
            <a>A very long sentence.</a>
            <a>Magnify this sentence.</a>
         </p>
      </ul>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check">
      Magnify
   </body>
</html>
```

**javasc.sc**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('a').hover(function(){
                $(this).animate({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'},50);
            },
            function(){
             $(this).animate({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'},50);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**lines.css**

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen click event. Change event will trigger on value changes. in your case value never changes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('a').hover(function(){
                $(this).animate({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'},50);
            },
            function(){
             $(this).animate({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'},50);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

also what you are doing here is just attaching a new event listener to $('a') element when it is checked. but you never remove that listener. so once you click it is there and always there.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
        if(input[type="checkbox"][name="check"].checked) {
            $(this).animate({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'},50);
        }else {
             $(this).animate({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'},50);
        };
    });
});
```

**UPDATE **

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
        if($('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).animate({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'},50);
        };
    }, function() {
          $(this).animate({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'},50);
    });
});
```

so basically on your hover listener, you check if that checkbox element is checked. and zoom in that case. if button is not checked, it won't make any changes. if it is checked and you mouse out, then it will revert back.

[Codepen for working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvvajW)

Comment: This is my first time using Jquery and JavaScript. Could you clarify? I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: It doesn't magnify at all now

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this code quite a bit by simply defining a "magnified" class and then just apply it or remove it as necessary. Just by setting up a CSS `transition` property, you can remove the `animate` calls.

Then, you need to either set up a `mouseover` event handler for the `a` elements or not, depending on whether the checkbox is checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chk = document.getElementById("check");
  var anchors = $('a');
  
  chk.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(chk.checked) {
      anchors.on("mouseover", mag); 
    } else {
      anchors.off("mouseover");
      anchors.removeClass("magnified");
    }

    function mag(evt){
       $(evt.target).addClass("magnified");
    }
 
  });
  
});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition:1s all;
}

.magnified {
  font-size:30px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<p>
  <a>This is a sentece.</a>
  <a>A very long sentence.</a>
  <a>Magnify this sentence.</a>
</p>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">
Magnify
```